# Question about how to show that something is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Fix a positive integer $n$ and consider the function $v:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $v(t)=(1,t,t^2,\cdots,t^{n-1})$. Show that $\{v(a_1),v(a_2),\cdots,v(a_n)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whenever $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ are distinct.

So, effectively, this question is saying, if $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are distinct, show that the set of $n$-tuples $\{(1,a_i,\cdots,a_i^{n-1}): i=1,2,\cdots,n\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is clear that these are linearly independent, but how do I show that they span $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: You have $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^n$. So, it's a basis, isn't it?

Comment: @amsmath Ha! *facepalm*. This question is literally asking "do you understand what it means for something to be a basis?" Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show that $\{v(a_i)\}$ forms a basis, we need to show that for all $x\in R^n$, there exist real coefficients $\beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots \beta_n$ such that 
$$x = \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i v(a_i).$$

This is true if $$x_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i a_i^{\,j-1}$$ for all $j\in\{1, \ldots, n\}$.  That is a linear system of equations

$$V \beta = x$$

where $\beta$ and $x$ are column vectors and $V$ is the [Vandermonde Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) with $V_{ji}=a_i^{\,j-1}$.  The Varndermonde is invertable if the $a_i$ are distinct, so we have shown that the $\beta_i$ exist and thus the set $\{v(a_i)\}$ is a basis.

Comment: The actual task here is to show that the Vandermonde matrix is invertible.